# Will a machine learning model be changed if passed as a parameter?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am creating a machine learning algorithm in python.
Say I have:

```
alg = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=1)
```

then I create a function fit

```
def fit(X,Y,alg):
  alg.fit(X,Y)
```

and in my main I call

```
fit(X, Y, alg)
Y_pred = alg.predict(X_test)
```

Will this work? Or alg is never really changed outside fit?

I have read this question [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference) but it is confusing since I do not know how my variable `alg` is changed.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the model object you pass to that function is mutable and is mutated by the `fit` method. Python's evaluation strategy is [call-by-sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing), so the changes will be reflected in the caller.

> Call by sharing (also referred to as call by object or call by
>   object-sharing) is an evaluation strategy first named by Barbara
>   Liskov et al. for the language CLU in 1974.[5] It is used by languages
>   such as Python,[6] Iota,[7] Java (for object references), Ruby,
>   JavaScript, Scheme, OCaml, AppleScript, and many others. However, the
>   term "call by sharing" is not in common use; the terminology is
>   inconsistent across different sources. For example, in the Java
>   community, they say that Java is call by value. Call by sharing
>   implies that values in the language are based on objects rather than
>   primitive types, i.e. that all values are "boxed".
>
> The semantics of call by sharing differ from call by reference in that
>   assignments to function arguments within the function aren't visible
>   to the caller (unlike by reference semantics)[citation needed], so
>   e.g. if a variable was passed, it is not possible to simulate an
>   assignment on that variable in the caller's scope. However, since the
>   function has access to the same object as the caller (no copy is
>   made), mutations to those objects, if the objects are mutable, within
>   the function are visible to the caller, which may appear to differ
>   from call by value semantics. Mutations of a mutable object within the
>   function are visible to the caller because the object is not copied or
>   cloned — it is shared.